# Passing multiple arguments in form of Dataframe and Arrays to fsolve in Python

Tags: python, optimization, converters, solver, equation-solving

I am trying to convert a matlab code into Python and need a help with fsolve function.
The Matlab function is of form

{`[beta0,val,exitflag] = fsolve(@(beta) solve_obj(beta,y,x,z,z1), tb);`}

where, y,x,z and z1 are given arguments and function need to solve for "beta" with tb as the initial guess.
y,x are dataframes and z and z1 are boolean arrays.

I am trying to find appropriate replacement in python but I am unable to figure out how to pass the arguments as an input. I tried to use below function.

{`from scipy.optimize import fsolve
beta0 =  fsolve(solve_obj, tb, (y,x,z,z1))`}

but it gives error that 
"solve_obj() takes 2 positional arguments but 5 were given"

Can you please suggest how the arguments in form of Dataframe and array can be passed for fsolve in Python

Comment: Looks like you need to post more information. `solve_obj` should be "A function that takes at least one (possibly vector) argument, and returns a value of the same length" and is of the format `f(x, *args)`. The way you have your call structured your are passing x (with first guess `tb`), followed by four arguments `(y,x,z,z1)`. If you want those passed as a single vector, pass them as `([y,x,z,z1])`.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html

Comment: thanks a lot, I figured out a mistake in the code. I wasn't passing the argument as *args and I was just passing the list. 
Thanks for the help.